How can you manage a JWT with server side rendering in Next.js?
The issue is with making API calls in a Next.js application using Axios, specifically when dealing with public APIs and APIs requiring an access token. Here's a structured explanation of the problem:
Interceptor Issue:
You have set up an Axios interceptor to handle the addition of the access token for API calls. However, on the server side, the interceptor is not picking the token from cookies or local storage. This is expected since these storage mechanisms are only available on the client side.
Workaround in the App Directory:
To solve the issue for server-side API calls, you created a custom Axios instance in the app/api/users directory and configured it to handle tokens. This solution works for API calls made within the app directory but fails when trying to use the same Axios instance in files within the components directory, as Next.js restricts app directory files from being used directly in components.

you can use cookies for the token instead of local storage. this is how i have done it.
create helper file and make sure to use the import 'server-only'; at the
the top
import 'server-only';
export enum COOKIES {
  JWT = 'token',
  RESEND_OTP_JWT = 'resend-otp-token',
  ACCEPT_COOKIES_POLICY = 'acceptCookies',
}
export const setSecureJwt = (tkn: string) => {
  cookies().set(COOKIES.JWT, tkn, {
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: true,
  });
};

in the loginAction when user login is succesfull you can set the cookies like this.
  setSecureJwt(jwt);

in the sever components you can read the cookies like this .

export const getAuthorizationHeader = () => {
  const token = cookies().get(COOKIES.JWT)?.value;
  if (!token) return false;
  return { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token };
};

